# Sending data to Devo with HTTP requests are received with unknown tags: "unknown.unknown"

Tags: database, http

I am trying to send data to Devo with HTTP requests. The request works and 204 status is received. I am following [Devo docs](https://docs.devo.com/confluence/ndt/sending-data-to-devo/other-data-collection-methods/http-endpoint) where this method is explained.

I can search the data in Devo but it is contained in unknown.unknown table. What am I doing wrong?

```
http://http-us.logtrust.io/event/MY_DOMAIN/token!MY_TOKEN/local1/XXXX.test.example?hello_world_message
```

Previously I created the token with target table: XXXX.test.* (where XXXX is the name of the project).

Answer (score 1):

After spending some time I found the answer in one of the Devo docs:
https://docs.devo.com/confluence/ndt/supported-technologies/special-devo-tags-and-data-tables

The problem was I was using "XXXX.test" as tag when first and second positions of the tags define the technology to parse the data. In this case, it is a custom application so it is necessary to use "my.app".

Before execute request it was necessary to create a new token for the new tags to use: "my.app.test.*"

Now I can visualize the data in Devo.